# Delete the text widget contents using perl_tk

Tags: perltk

If we want to remove the entry widget contents we can use delete
with entry object.

Example

```
$ent->delete(0,'end');
```

But I want to remove the Text widget contents.Can any one tell me what is the function for removing the text widget contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following way

> use Tk;
>
> use Tk::Text ;
>
> .... 
>   .....
>
> my $txt = $mw->Text( -background
>   =>'white', )-> pack ();
>
> $txt -> delete('1.0','end');

Refer the Links.
http://legacyweb.triumf.ca/people/cpayne/perl/Tk/Text.html>Tk::Text